# Firebase Hosting Custom Domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I recently bought a domain and tried to connect it to my running firebase app.
Since the site I bought the domain from doesn't provide a management tool, they set the DNS records for me. Now the domain has status 'Connected' on the hosting dashboard but when I open the page, nothing is shown.

Do I have to keep something in mind here?
The domain I am talking about has some files on the ftp like index.php.
Do I have to delete all of this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to be able to update the DNS records for Firebase Hosting. If you can't do it yourself give the details Google provides to the host.

Comment: For claification: I provided all the Records from the firebase setup to the provider and it states 'Connected', so I did all of that!

Comment: My mistake, I misread the details.

Comment: Do you have an index.html file in the root of your hosting directory?

Comment: No there is a html folder with a index.php. What would I need an index.html for?

Comment: Have fixed or still searching a solution?  Before to reply, be sure that you have access to update DNS records, provided by domain seller.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by waiting 48 hours, didn't think the DNS propagation would take that long.

Comment: did you have to change something in the firebase.json file to view the deployed site on your custom domain?